# Slow distinct PostgreSQL query on nested jsonb field won't use index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to get distinct values from a nested field on JSONB column, but it takes about 2 minutes on a 400K rows table.
The original query used `DISTINCT` but then I read that `GROUP BY` works better so tried this too, but no luck - still extremely slow.

Adding an index did not help either:

```
create index "orders_financial_status_index" on orders ((data ->'data'->> 'financial_status'));
```

`ANALYZE EXPLAIN` gave this result:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=13431.16..13431.22 rows=4 width=32) (actual time=123074.941..123074.943 rows=4 loops=1)
  Group Key: ((data -> 'data'::text) ->> 'financial_status'::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..12354.14 rows=430809 width=32) (actual time=2.993..122780.325 rows=434080 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.119 ms
Execution time: 123074.979 ms
```

It's worth mentioning that there are no null values on this column, and currently there are 4 unique values.

What should I do in order to query the distinct values faster?

Comment: What is your actual query BTW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No index will make this faster, because the query has to scan the whole table.

As you can see, the sequential scan uses almost all the time; the hash aggregate is fast.

Still I would not drop the index, because it allows PostgreSQL to estimate the number of groups accurately and decide on the more efficient hash aggregate rather than sorting the rows. You can try without the index to be sure.

However, two minutes for half a million rows is not very fast. Do you have slow storage? Is the table bloated? If the latter, `VACUUM (FULL)` should improve things.

You can speed up the query by reducing I/O. Load the table into RAM with [pg_prewarm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgprewarm.html), then processing should be considerably faster.

Comment: Using Google Cloud as storage, 1 vCPU and 3.75 GB memory. It's not very performant - but does quite well for all other operations.
About table bloat, it might be the case, I didn't know this term until now. Will try to run `VACUUM (FULL)` and see if it helps

Comment: Unfortunately VACUUMing didn't help - it still take about the same time.
I think that the machine might be just too weak :(

Comment: Yes. Either get enough RAM to buffer the whole database, or get faster I/O.

Comment: Update: Upgraded the machine to 12 GB RAM (whole DB takes 9 GB). Unfortunately the query is still running slow (it went down from about 2 minutes to 1:20. Any other ideas?